# Android Facebook SDK - username is getting null

Tags: android, android-facebook, android-simple-facebook

I am using [simple facebbok](https://github.com/sromku/android-simple-facebook) to integrate facebook to my application.i need to send the facebook username to server.but i got the username as null from profile listner.
here is my code

```
   public void loginToFacebook(View v){
    mSimpleFacebook.login(this);
}
OnLoginListener listner = new OnLoginListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLogin() {
        mSimpleFacebook.getProfile(onProfileListener);
    }
};
OnProfileListener onProfileListener = new OnProfileListener() {         
    @Override
    public void onComplete(Profile profile) {
        System.out.println(profile.getUsername());//getting null here
    }
};
```

I have also tried with the code,

```
OnLoginListener listner = new OnLoginListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLogin() {
    Profile.Properties properties = new Profile.Properties.Builder()
    .add(Properties.USER_NAME)
    .add(Properties.ID)
    .build();
    mSimpleFacebook.getProfile(properties, onProfileListener);
    }
};
```

But the listner is not getting fired in this case.

This is the permission i have given in the Application class

```
private void configureFacebook() {
       Permission[] permissions = new Permission[] {
                Permission.USER_ABOUT_ME,
                Permission.PUBLIC_PROFILE,
                Permission.READ_STREAM,
                Permission.EMAIL,
                Permission.PUBLISH_ACTION
            };
       SimpleFacebookConfiguration configuration = new SimpleFacebookConfiguration.Builder()
        .setAppId(Constants.FB_APPID)
        .setNamespace("namespace")
        .setPermissions(permissions)
        .build();
       SimpleFacebook.setConfiguration(configuration);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get username in API v2.0

Comment: True story. The library should be updated and username property should be removed.

Comment: But in ios they are getting the username.

Comment: And it is the same app_id that you use?

Comment: No app_id is different

Comment: That explains it. You other app is an old one so it can still use API v1.0. But this one can't

Comment: Oh so if i  use the API v1.0 i can get the username is it ?

Comment: Yes, but if your app wasn't active before 4/30/2014 you can not use API v1.0

Comment: One more doubt if i use the same appId of ioS then can i get the userName

Comment: Yes you can use the same App ID. But it just mean that both of your apps will break at 4/30/2015

Comment: But iOS app is registered to facebook before 4/30/2014

Comment: Yes. That means you have until 4/30/2015 to upgrade to api v2.0